# findDOMNode() For Select Element Not Working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component, react-dom, react-class-based-component

I have a form with select element. The values for options for select element comes from an API. So, I have to dynamically create the options. But, I am unable to get the select element from `DOM`.

Following is the code that have tried. I tried to access select ID element with `findDOMNode`. None of this is getting the element.

What do I need to do to get the element selected?

```
    componentDidMount() {
      companyUserNames()
        .then(result => {
          const companyUsername = result;
          console.log(result);
          //output  ==> [   { userName: "ABC",fullName: "ABC XYZ"}, {userName: 
          //      "DEF",fullName: "DEF QRW"}]


          companyUsername.forEach(role => {
            console.log(role);

            const roledynamic1 = document.getElementById("name1");
            console.log(roledynamic3);
            //output = null

            const roledynamic2 = this.refs.name1
            console.log(roledynamic3);
            //output = undefiend
            
            const roledynamic3 = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.name1)
            console.log(roledynamic3);
            //output = null
         
            const newchild1 = document.createElement("option");
            newchild1.value = role.userName;
            newchild1.text = role.fullName;
            roledynamic3.add(newchild1);
          });
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }

    render(){
        return(
         <form>
        //some input field

            <div className='select'>
              <select
                name='userName'
                id='name1'
                ref="name1"
                className='input common-input-style'
                maxLength='255'
                value={this.state.userName.value}
                onChange={this.handleInputChange}
               >
                  <option>Name</option>
               </select>
            </div>

        //some input field
        <form/>
         )
    }
```

Comment: You should avoid string Refs and [use `createRef()` instead](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactcreateref). Are you passing the ref to the form inputs?

Comment: yes I am passing the refs to form inputs @AminPaks

Comment: Then you should have direct access to DOM after component mounted.

Answer (score 2):

[findDOMNode](http://findDOMNode) accepts a `component` as an argument, not a ref.
Try using the `ref` directly it should hold the DOM node.

Note that `findDOMNode` is a deprecated API and should be avoided.

Also, as Amin Paks mentioned you should consider switching to the current style of using refs with `createRef`

Comment: Too bad most React libraries haven't addressed this change.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to access DOM node when you can easily work with state in react.

Below is the working code with [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-elbakyan-lpjz5):-

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    names: []
  };
  companyUserNames = () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      return resolve([
        { userName: "ABC", fullName: "ABC XYZ" },
        { userName: "DEF", fullName: "DEF QRW" }
      ]);
    });
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.companyUserNames()
      .then(result => {
        this.setState({
          names: result
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
  render() {
    const { names } = this.state;
    let namesList =
      names.length > 0 &&
      names.map((item, i) => {
        return (
          <option key={i} value={item.userName}>
            {item.fullName}
          </option>
        );
      });
    return (
      <form>
        <div className="select">
          <select className="input common-input-style" maxLength="255">
            {namesList}
          </select>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```